# Why do people who work in stochastic analysis and geometry tend to work in sub Riemannian geometry?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, sub-riemannian-geometry

There is a rich theory of diffusions on manifolds. Every time I see someone who studies diffusions on manifolds, it seems like they study the sub Riemannian setting. I get that this is more general than Riemannian, but what is so special about this case? Why can't you generalize Riemannian in different ways?